# Embedded Flash Security

Tags: javascript, flash, security

I had a discussion with my colleague about Flash security. We're in the phase of planning some things for our web project that is using Flash plugin to display content. We need to dynamically pull settings for the Flash application from the server, using JSON.

Proposal that I offered was that we should save an extra HTTP request to pull the data file after the plugin is loaded and embed the JSON directly in the page containing the Flash plugin. Flash would fire a Javascript function that'd return the deserialized JSON data to it.

My colleague opposed this proposal with significant "security concerns".

I believe that there's literally zero difference between these two approaches besides the fact that his approach requires additional HTTP request. All of this is client/server and client should never be trusted. If I want to change the data that is in the JSON query, I can do that in both cases. File pull is little more difficult to hack though, but possible with custom HTTP proxy.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: My only thought to add is that your flash could be used to run a javascript function that does more than just get settings...

Comment: @jswolf19 the same problem exists with just plain js though, and as long as the swf and all loaded contents are in Napalm's control there is no danger that the flash's ExternalInterface would be subverted.  @Napalm : I think your colleague's objections stem from the fact that if you embed the json on the page, you make it easier for someone to see your data structure, study it, and determine how to maliciously attack you.  Problem is that his method isn't immune to this, it just means that the hacker would have to examine the traffic logs with firebug or charles to get the same data.  Trivial.

Comment: @scriptocalypse, I'm aware that the same problem exists with just plain js, but if the flash program is embedded on another page, perhaps one mimicing Napalm's page, then I'm not sure how the interaction would work... Would such a page be able to for example set cookies on Napalm's domain? I'm not familiar enough with how security is done in either to say anything for certain.

Comment: @jswolf19 Well, a swf file can be domain locked, such that it functions only on a given domain (not completely immune to the efforts of a determined hacker, but depending on the construction of the swf, a hurdle bigger than watching traffic logs).  As for cookies, I'm less knowledgeable about browser cookies created and set by js, but Flash's shared-objects are domain-specific so simply embedding the swf on a different domain won't give the hacker access to Napalm's Shared Objects and writing cross-domain sharedobjects isn't really doable anyway as far as I know. More to come...

Comment: Also, if the swf on Napalm's site requests data from Napalm's server at any time, the server should have a record of some fishy domain attempting to gain access to the data, so if the content were being stolen it shouldn't be hard to trace it back to the thieves.  If there are no direct calls to the server, then the thieves have to go to the trouble of mocking up their own server.  By the way, I'm not trying to argue in favor one way or the other of the relative security of swf vs js (neither is particularly secure).  At this point I'm just musing.

Comment: @scrtipocalypse, I'm not arguing so much as curious myself ^_^. If for some reason Napalm wants to allow his swf to be included on other sites, then there might be more for him to consider before going a js route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you really care that much about delivering original settings to the .swf:

- don't use http - httpFox is a brilliant plugin - use a server that supports RTMP/RTMPE and `NetConnection.call()` to retrieve the data.
- create an algorithm for validating original json so that your app won't work if the config doesn't pass the test.
- after the config is loaded your swf might check the values with the server (not all at a time) and throw an error if something goes wrong

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference. Both can be fabricated.